# How do I return functions with inout parameters and a return type of Void in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function

I have attempted to run this code in an Xcode 6.0 playground and in an iOS project through the viewController `viewDidLoad` function, and in both settings the program crashes the compiler. I have read about people having similar issues when returning inout functions when the program is run through a playground, however the issue was resolved when they ran their program through a project. Is something incorrect with my code, and if so what is wrong, or am I running the code incorrectly in the playground or project?

```
// testingPlayground
// July 18, 2015


func chooseFunction(isYNegative lessThanZero: Bool) -> (inout Int) -> Void {
    func increaseY(inout #yValue: Int){ // Increases yValue
        yValue += 1
    }

    func decreaseY(inout #yValue: Int){ // Decreases yValue
        yValue -= 1
    }

    return lessThanZero ? increaseY : decreaseY // Returns either the increase or decrease yValue function
}


var yValue = -1
var changeYFunction = chooseFunction(isYNegative: yValue < 0)


while yValue != 0 {
    changeYFunction(&yValue) // Increments/Decrements yValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me after removing the `#` from both of the `#yValue: Int` parameters inside `chooseFunction` (having the `#` would imply that an argument name must be given, which you don't do).

Alternatively, you need to specify the parameter name in the return type of `chooseFunction` and use it when you call the returned function, i.e.:

```
func chooseFunction(isYNegative lessThanZero: Bool) -> ((inout yValue: Int) -> Void) {
```

And:

```
changeYFunction(yValue: &yValue)
```

In other words, the problem is that you are not consistent with whether or not the returned functions require a name for the argument or not.

**edit**: As yet another alternative, you could consider refactoring the whole thing, e.g., use the shorthand for curried functions:

```
func stepper(increase increase: Bool)(inout _ y: Int) {
    increase ? ++y : --y
}
var y = -5
let step = stepper(increase: y < 0)
while y != 0 {
    step(&y)
}
```

In fact, even the following works, although the hairy syntax required makes me wary:

```
func stepper(increase increase: Bool)(inout _ y: Int)() {
    increase ? ++y : --y
}
var y = -5
let stepY = stepper(increase: y < 0)(&y)
while y != 0 {
    stepY()
}
```

Comment: I edited my code to reflect your edits and the same error persisted. I instead reverted back to my original code and avoided using inout parameters and instead directly returned a value from the increaseY and decreaseY functions and made some minor modifications within the while block; with these modifications my code ran as it was supposed to. I am curious as to which version of xCode you are using as I do believe this may be an error in the older version of xCode I am using.

Comment: @MrBillingsly I tried with both 6.4 and 7 beta 3, actually. I edited the answer for yet another alternative solution.